# Pulses counting problem from npn proximity with interrupts in arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupts, emc, proximity-sensor

I am interfacing an open output npn proximity sensor with Arduino nano. I have used very silly approach of voltage divider as I was not sure that in open output sensor you can get whatever voltage you want on signal with pull-up resistor with desired supply voltage.

Following is the schematics of circuit I am using.

[image: cleaned-up image]

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Wvn.jpg))

I am using an interrupt to count pulses from sensor. Normally, the arduino counts the pulses fine, but when stepper motors are activated or thermal printer is activated, my arduino counts more pulses than it should and activates an output before it should. I guessed that culprit is npn pulses because when I don't give signal to the printer and motors, the behaviour is predictable and according to expectation. But when the motors and thermal printer are turned on, stamp activation is more random.
Now to tackle this problem, I have two options

1. to modify hardware (need suggestions in this regard as whether should I add optocoupler or Schmitt trigger or simple capacitor to minimize effect of EMI)
2. to modify software intead of counting fixed time period pulses use internal timers to put delay (In this regard I want to know, do timer library effect serial communication or delay functions as I am reading serial data from serial shift register IC 4021)

---

```
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int SENSORS = 128;  // TOTAL number of sensors
const int modules = SENSORS/8;   // no of sensor modules
const int mid = 64 ;    // Sensor # parallel to stamp figures
const int preset = 165; //# of cm  actuall value around 100
const int stampOntime = 25; // How long stamp remain pressed acuall around 25

// pins 
const int led = 12;     // IR led strip
const int latch =  11;
const int cloc = 10;
const int daata = 5;
const int stampPin = 17;     // stamp  pin
const byte proximityPin = 2;    // proximity sensor pulses
const byte checkPin = 3;      // from main controler to call check function
const byte statusPin =  8;  // status of connectivity of sensor bar

volatile byte state = 3;    // do nothing state
volatile byte state2 = 0;

int counter= 0, counter2 = 0, midSensor = 0 ,len=0 , wid = 0;
unsigned int sum = 0;
byte add = 0, stamp = 0 ;
byte bufferr[modules+1];  //to store data for checking . check if it works with local variable 


//functions

void sample();
void chk();
int readData();
int checkSensors();

//SoftwareSerial port(7,9 );  //rx tx

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(stampPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latch, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(cloc,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(daata,INPUT);
  pinMode(proximityPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(checkPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(statusPin,INPUT);


//  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(proximityPin), sample, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(checkPin), chk, RISING);

  Serial.begin(57600);
//port.begin(9600);
    digitalWrite(latch, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(cloc, LOW);
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
  int c=0;
  byte req ;
  if (state == 1)
  {
   c = readData();
   state = LOW;
   if (c>1)
   {
    if(c>wid)
  //  wid=c;
    add=1;
  //  len++;
  c=c<<1;
    sum+=c;
   }
   else if(add == 1)
   {
    Serial.print(sum);
  //  Serial.println(wid);
  //  Serial.println(len);

    sum = 0;
    add = 0;
    len = 0;
    wid = 0;
   }
   if(state2 == 0)
    {
      if(c>0)
      {
      if(midSensor == 1)
        state2 = 2;
      else
        state2 = 1;
      }
    }
   else if(state2 == 1)
    {
      if(midSensor == 1)

      state2 = 2;
    }
   else if(state2 == 2)
   { 

    if(midSensor == 0)
      state2 = 3;

   }
   else if(state2 == 3)
    {
      if(c == 0)
      state2 = 4;
      else if(midSensor == 1)
       {
        state2 = 2;
        counter = 0;
       }
    } 
   if(counter >= preset)
    {

      digitalWrite(stampPin,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      stamp = 1;
      state2 = 0; 
      counter = 0;
      }
    if(stamp == 1)
      counter2++;
    if(counter2 >=stampOntime)
    {
      digitalWrite(stampPin,LOW);
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);
      stamp = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
    }

//port.print(F(" c = "));      
//port.print(c);
//port.print(F(" midSenor= "));      
//port.print(midSensor);
//port.print(F(" state2= "));      
//port.print(state2);
//port.print(F(" stamp "));      
//port.print(stamp);
//port.print(F("   counter= "));
//port.print(counter);
//port.print(F(" counter2= "));
//port.println(counter2);
  }
  else if( state == 2)
  {
    checkSensors();
    state = 3;
  }
  else if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    req=Serial.read();
    if(req == 4)
    state = 0; //   ready for measurement
    else
    state = 3; // go into halt position
    }

//Serial.println(state);
}


int readData(){
   int n=0,d=0;
   int i=0;
noInterrupts();
  //Serial.print("in readData");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   
  //delay(1); 
  delayMicroseconds(1000);   
  digitalWrite(latch,LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);

// just for checking purpose

//  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
//  delayMicroseconds(10);
//  digitalWrite(latch,HIGH);
//  delayMicroseconds(1000);
//  digitalWrite(latch,LOW);
//  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
//  
  for(i=SENSORS-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    n= digitalRead(daata);
    if(n==0)                // check either c 0 or c 1 if(c!=0)
     d++;
    if (i == mid)
      midSensor = !n;
    //Serial.println(i);


    digitalWrite(cloc, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(30);//30
    digitalWrite(cloc, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(25);//20
  }
  digitalWrite(latch,HIGH);
 //Serial.println(d);
 interrupts();
  return d;
}

int checkSensors(){

 // noInterrupts();
   int n1=0,d1=0;
   int i1=0,j1=0 , st=0;
  // byte bufferr[modules+1];  //to store data for checking . check if it works with local variable 


   //  port.println("In check sensor");
     st=readData();
     if(st == 0)
     bufferr[0] = 0;    // to indicate sensors OK
     else 
     bufferr[0] = 1;    // To indicate some sensors not OK

     st = digitalRead(statusPin);
     if(st == 1)
     bufferr[0] = 2;    // to indicate sensor bar not connected
     delay(20);

digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
// digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delayMicroseconds(1000);   
  digitalWrite(latch,LOW);   // Ready for serial data out
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);   // turn the LED off (HIGH is the voltage level)
//  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // 
  for(i1=modules; i1>0; i1--)
  { 
    for(j1=7; j1>=0; j1--)
    {
    n1= digitalRead(daata);
 //   port.print(n1);
    if (n1 == 0)
    bufferr[i1] = bufferr[i1] | (1 << j1);


    digitalWrite(cloc, HIGH);  
    delayMicroseconds(30); // 30
    digitalWrite(cloc, LOW);  
    delayMicroseconds(30); //30
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(latch,HIGH);

  Serial.write(bufferr,modules+1);    // check whether this function works   
  //Serial.write(bufferr[0]);
 // Serial.write(bufferr[1]);
 // Serial.write(bufferr[2]);

/*  
  port.print(" B0 ");
  port.print(bufferr[0]);
  port.print("  B1 ");
  port.print(bufferr[16]);
   port.print("  B2 ");
  port.println(bufferr[15]);
*/  
//   port.print("  ");
   Serial.flush();
   // port.println(d1);3

   for( i1=0;i1<=modules;i1++)
   bufferr[i1]=0;   // reset buffer for next value;
  // interrupts();
  return d1;
}
void sample(){
  if(state2 == 3 || state2 == 4)
  counter++;
 if(state == 0)
  state = 1;
 // digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
 // Serial.print("int");
}
void chk(){
  state=2;
}
```

Comment: Why are you dividing your 12 V by two to give a 6 V input to the microcontroller? That doesn't look good. You shouldn't need those resistors and a single pull-up to +5 V is what is required. You can use the internal pull-up or, for noise immunity, use a 1k external pull-up to 5 V. The NPN will look after pulling low.

Comment: In your sketch, you did not connect the two grounds.  That could be a problem.  Are they really not connected?

Comment: @Transistor You are right. I should have used this approach. but will it be more immune to noise than my appoach of voltage divider?

Comment: @scorpdaddy both grounds are connected

Comment: Edit your question to explain why you are using a potential divider and why you think that will help. We can address that then and help you with some theory.

Comment: @saki, connected how?  and where does the 12 V come from?  where does the 5V come from?

Comment: @scorpdaddy I am using single SMPS with 12V and 5v outputs. I have connected grounds of that supply.

Comment: If you know the pulse width your looking for, you can add a low pass RC filter that is ~5x the frequency of your pulse... I.e. f_cut=5 x 1/(t_width). It should provide enough bandwidth for you to edge detect without to much of an issue.

Comment: For now I have used millis() to produce required delay. But I need suggestions to improve my system for better EMI immunity.